# Trying to requery an already closed cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, illegalstateexception

I'm doing simply queries like:

```
Cursor c = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select " + MyTable.TABLE_FIELD.getColumnName() + " from " + MyTable.TABLE_NAME, null);
```

after that I extract the data needed and populate some views.

```
c.close();
```

Everything works as expected. I have a share intent to send an e-mail with some of the information shown. The `java.lang.IllegalStateException` is thrown after the e-mail app sends the e-mail or closes and my activity is brought back to "life".
This exception is only thrown in this situation, if I send it to background and then call it again this exception isn't thrown. I even have an intent to open youtube and play a video and this exception isn't thrown...

I really don't know why this is happening.

Thanks for your time.

ps: I've tried `//c.close();` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was causing this problem. Some of the e-mail's information was fed by another cursor from an "utils" class. This cursor was closed after providing the information to the e-mail and this was causing the problem. Instead of `c.close();` I changed to `c = null;` and now it's working.

Probably not the best solution, but for now it's working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `c.requery()` but it  was deprecated in API level 11.

> Don't use this. Just request a new cursor, so you can do this
>   asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes
>   back.
>
> Performs the query that created the cursor again, refreshing its
>   contents. This may be done at any time, including after a call to
>   deactivate(). Since this method could execute a query on the database
>   and potentially take a while, it could cause ANR if it is called on
>   Main (UI) thread. A warning is printed if this method is being
>   executed on Main thread.

Comment: I think the best policy is something like this: http://helpmeco.de/2012/3/using-an-android-cursor-loader-with-a-content-provider

Comment: Right but your question was something different ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClassName.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    super.onStop();

}
```